# php and MYSQL INSERT error

Tags: php, mysql

I am currently in a condition not to find any errors in this line of code. I am trying to add several data to mysql database using PHP.

It gets "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'geo')' at line 5" Error message when I try to register someone. "geo" is the value of the radio group element.

```
<?php
if($_GET["regname"] && $_GET["regemail"] && $_GET["regpass1"] 
   && $_GET["regpass2"]&& $_GET["regfamilyname"] 
   && $_GET["reggivenname"] && $_GET["radioGroup"] )
{
    if($_GET["regpass1"]==$_GET["regpass2"])
    {
       $servername="localhost";
       $database="aaa";
       $username="bbbb";
       $password="cccc";

       $conn=  mysql_connect($servername,$username, $password) 
               or die(mysql_error());
       mysql_select_db($database,$conn);

       $sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,familyname, 
             email, givenname, is_admin, created_time, category) values 
             ('" . $_GET["regname"] . "', '" .$_GET["regpass"]. "', '" 
             .$_GET["regfamilyname"]. "','" .$_GET["regemail"]. "', '" 
             .$_GET["reggivenname"]. "', '0', NOW()', '" 
             .$_GET["radioGroup"]. "')";

       $result=mysql_query($sql,$conn) or die(mysql_error());          
       print "<h1>You have registered sucessfully</h1>"; 
       print "<a href='index.php'>Go to login page</a>";
    }
    else print "Passwords doesnt match.";
}
    else print"Invalid data;";
?>
```

Comment: You definitely read [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/60496/569101) to avoid any SQL injetion !

Comment: What's the error message ? How far does your script work (echo something somewhere to see if the "if" cases work). Echo the $sql to see the query...

Comment: by the way, are you trying to build a login script ? There are some good ones out there...

Comment: Yes it is an login page's php. There isn't any specific error message, but the error is inside the $sql

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hard to say, because you haven't provided error message.

I guess error is here:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (id,username,password,familyname, email, givenname, is_admin, created_time, category) values ('','$_GET["regname"]', '$_GET["regpass"]', '$_GET["regfamilyname"]', '$_GET["regemail"]', '$_GET["reggivenname"]', '0', NOW()', '$radiobutton')";
```

You are inserting empty string into `id` column. Try fixing it, by removing `id` and `''`, there are also some quotes related problems:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,familyname, email, givenname, is_admin, created_time, category) values ('".$_GET["regname"]."', '".$_GET["regpass"]."', '".$_GET["regfamilyname"]."', '".$_GET["regemail"]."', '".$_GET["reggivenname"]."', '0', NOW(), '".$radiobutton."')";
```

This is probably not working because you have defined `id` filed as `int PRIMARY KEY` with `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

Also you are using old `mysql_*` functions, in a way wich leads to sql inejction vulnerabilities. You can use PDO with prepared statements.

**UPDATE**:

- [PDO tutorial](http://wiki.hashphp.org/PDO_Tutorial_for_MySQL_Developers)
- [MySQL Primary Ket auto_increment](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/example-auto-increment.html)
- [PHP quotes](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php)

Comment: id is an primary key. I want to increase the id number when I add a user. For example first users id will be 1, seconds will be 2. How can I do it?

Comment: NEW ERROR: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'geo')' at line 5

Comment: geo is the value of the radio group element

Comment: I had small typo (additional `'` near `NOW()`) so I've edited my post. I believe that this could be fixed by you.

Comment: Also make sure that there is no `'` in any of your `$_GET` variables, like I said the way you write your script leads to sql injection vulnerabilities.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the query will break because all the terms like `'$_GET["regname"]'` which will break it using the `"`. You can use concatenation if you want to do it this way:

```
$sql="INSERT INTO users (username,password,familyname, 
email, givenname, is_admin, created_time, category) values 
('" . $_GET["regname"] . "', '" .$_GET["regpass"]. "', '" .$_GET["regfamilyname"]. "',
  '" .$_GET["regemail"]. "', '" .$_GET["reggivenname"]. "', '0', 
  NOW()', '" . $radiobutton. "')";
```

But a better practice will be using [PDO.](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)
**An example:**

```
$stmt = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO users (username,password,familyname, 
email, givenname, is_admin, created_time, category) values 
(:username,:password,:familyname,:email,:givenname,:is_admin,:created_time,:category)");

$taValues = array(
 'username'   =>  $_GET["regname"],
 'password'   =>  $_GET["regpass"],
 'familyname' =>  $_GET["regfamilyname"],
 'email'      =>  $_GET["regemail"],
 'givenname'  =>  $_GET["reggivenname"],
 'is_admin'   => '0',
 'created_time'  =>  NOW(),
 'category'      =>  $radiobutton
); 

PDOBindArray($stmt,$taValues);

$stmt->execute();
```

Comment: NEW ERROR occurs when hitting register button: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '', 'geo')' at line 5

Comment: geo is the radio button value

Comment: Without a dup of the variables it's hard to say. use `echo` or `print_r` to print the variable and print also the query. update your  question with all this info and let's see what we can find.